# Erro usando a lib Requests (python 3.8)

Tags: python, python-3.x, microsoft-azure

Tenho uma VM na Azure onde não consigo rodar esse código:

```
import requests

url = 'https://apidatalake.tesouro.gov.br/ords/siconfi/tt/rreo?an_exercicio=2022&nr_periodo=1&co_tipo_demonstrativo=RREO&no_anexo=RREO-Anexo%2003&id_ente=1100205'

requests.get(url)
```

Era para retornar `<Response [200]>`

Mas recebo o erro:

```
raise ConnectionError(e, request=request)
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='apidatalake.tesouro.gov.br', port=443): 

Max retries exceeded with url: 

/ords/siconfi/tt/rreo?an_exercicio=2022&nr_periodo=1&co_tipo_demonstrativo=RREO&no_anexo=RREO-Anexo%2003&id_ente=1100205 

(Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7fa9a7352dc0>: Failed to establish a new connection: 

[Errno 110] Connection timed out'))
```

Essa é configuração:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**O que estou fazendo de errado?**

Comment: Por favor, edite a pergunta para limitá-la a um problema específico com detalhes suficientes para identificar uma resposta adequada.

Answer (score -1):

A causa desse problema pode ser vários, como por exemplo:

1. A API que você está acessando está demorando para responder.
2. A API está bloqueando o seu IP por ter ultrapassado o limite de requisições.
3. O servidor em que você está executando o script
   está bloqueando o acesso externo.

Mas aparentemente está faltando configurar as regras para saída para as portas 80/443. Porque a requisição está sendo realizada mas acaba dando time out.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Teste realizado na minha máquina local com resposta HTTP/200.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Oi, Fernando, obrigado pela resposta. Adicionei portas de saída 80 e 443, e nada. Então acho que não entendi bem como está sua configuração. Engraçado que na configuração inicial do print  eu consigo fazer requests de outras páginas como google, etc. Pensei que a api do Tesouro seja blacklisted,para outros países mas fiz alguns testes em outras máquinas e deu certo.